# Good practices for javascript/jquery website animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm trying to build a homepage that has a lot of moving elements. I've checked other websites that have the same moving animations do the same technique e.g. **move stuff** on `setInterval()`. But I don't know if it would be ok, on my computer its running smoothly. But I don't know if it would cause any damage to other users specifically slow computers. I say this because when I opened the site on my phone it got hot real fast.

I made a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XLHVh/1/) where you can see what kind of simple movements are happening but how fast the functions are executing. The fiddle only shows 4 elements but the homepage has about 10 more elements moving.

So what would be good practices to follow when implementing these kinds of website animations?

Comment: What versions of browsers are you targeting? If you want the latest and greatest, you aught to try out `requestAnimationFrame`. It should result in smoother and more power-efficient (for laptops and the like) animations. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame

Comment: I'll get my crystal ball now to see what the people of 2014 think about your animations ;) Nah just kidding, this is quite an interesting question as I was thinking of redesigning my site to contain some animations soon too. I noticed from your fiddle that you're using JS to do the animations though. Why not use CSS3 keyframes so you can take advantage of hardware acceleration on mobile devices?

Comment: Depends on the purpose of your site. Are you targeting the mobile platform? Is this sites' main goal to wow a mobile user with how awesome their phone can perform? Overall you should keep animations to a minimum to avoid sluggish response times on phones because it doesn't take much JS to bog down a mobile device especially if you care about Android 2.3

Comment: actually this is a general question no specific users. I'm looking for something that should be practiced no matter what the situation? is that possible?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my comment before you posted yours :) but overall you should keep animations to a minimum to avoid a sluggish UI

Comment: Also if this is a very general question then many people are going to generally assume IE8, IE9, IE10, IE11, all Chrome, all FireFox, all Safari, all Mobile browsers compatibility. The line has to be drawn somewhere if you want to take advantage of newer technologies. And if you want to implement newer technologies to run on old browsers then prepare yourself for some sluggishness no matter what you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setInterval` would be fine if you target old browsers, but it's not meant for animation. [Some browsers cap it to 4ms. Some won't slow down when the window is not focused](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2011/12/14/timer-resolution-in-browsers/), so it will eat up CPU cycles, and therefore power - not good when you're on a mobile device.

There's [requestAnimationFrame](http://caniuse.com/requestanimationframe), a timer that's optimized for animation. Animation slows down or halts when the window is not in focus, and it aims to draw at 60fps.

For minor, non-behavioral animation (style, rather than behavior), you can do [CSS animations instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations). One nice thing about CSS animations is that some of them, especially [the ones that deal with 3D, are GPU accelerated](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/21/play-with-hardware-accelerated-css/), making them faster and smoother than your make-shift JS animations.